# How to store result from MySQL for later sorting

Tags: mysql, algorithm, memcached, geospatial

I have a table that contains some text fields and latitude and longitude. I want to

(1). do a text search first (e.g. a simple LIKE search) and

(2). then sort by geolocation proximity. (given user's geolocation, sort the result from (1) by distance)

I want to make sure that the first result set (i.e. the list from text search) is cached so that it can be use for sorting different geolocation/user; that is if an user already searched "sushi", step (1) would not be repeated for later user searching "sushi".

Can this be done with MySQL? Or store the result from (1) in memcached? I guess fetching the result from memcached and then do sorting is probably not effiecient, as I am using php and I am not aware of any good way to do geo-spatial sorting there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds exactly the job for [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) a full-text search engine which supports geodistance calculations:

http://php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setgeoanchor.php